# How to pass fetched data from server to multiple screens out of stack navigator in react native using redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-redux-form

I have a login function that fetches the user info from mysql database. I want to send this data to different screens some of them are out of stack navigator. I was researching for a while and got to know that this could be done using redux, but i could not find a clear example on how to achieve that. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Here is my login function:

```
login = () => {
    if (this.state.inputFieldsStatus == true)
        {  
            // this.setState({passwordError:" Something went wrong! "})
            fetch('http://ip_Adress/login', {
                method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password,
                })
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {

                // alert(JSON.stringify(res.message));
            
                if (res.success === true ) {
                    // AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', 
                        // {
                        //     screen: 'Messages',
                        //     params: 
                        //         {
                        //             message: res.message,
                        //             otherParam: 'anything you want here'
                        //         } 
                        // },
                        {
                            screen: 'Profile',
                            params: 
                                {
                                    message: res.message,
                                    otherParam: 'anything you want here'
                                } 
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    this.setState({passwordError: res.message })
                    // alert(res.message);
                }
            })
            .done();
        }
        else 
            {
                // alert(' Please fill in all fields! ');
                this.setState({passwordError:" Please fill in all fields! "})
            }
}
```

Comment: I will suggest u to Store the data in context.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with redux, I don't see any code indicating you are using redux store?

Comment: try this [context api](https://github.com/minhtc/react-recontext)

Comment: @C.K Thank you so much :)

Comment: Did context API solve your problem? @User10

Comment: @C.K I wanted to do it with Redux, I succeeded but currently I have been researching for a week on how to pass the data fetched by redux without using flat-list :)